# How to wire a motion sensor light (no switch, always on) in the middle of a circuit/run?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am running electical wire in my shed. I have wired a motion sensor light fixure in the middle of the circuit. My plan was to always have power running to the fixture since it is a motion sensor. But I'm a little confused as to how I should wire it correctly. If the fixture is in the middle, does that mean I should mark the neutral coming from the fixture as hot, and wire the fixture neutral to the outgoing hot? Or do I simply connect all my hots together and neutrals together?

Like this?
[image]

Or like this?
[image]

Comment: @Ecnerwal I already added a diagram, but I think you added your comment before I finished adding the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way. Nothing (other than switches) is normally in series with any other device. All are in parallel across the hot/neutral.

Comment: I was totally overthinking it. But now I remember the difference between series and parallel. Thanks!